# Strange Maven3 error

Tags: maven, maven-3

all, I get this error when building with maven (`mvn clean install`).
Can't find the description of the problem. maybe anybody encountered it, what does it mean and how to fix it? How to force the updates?

```
Failure to find org.springframework:spring:jar:3.0.0.RELEASE in http://download.java.net/maven/2/ was cached in
the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Java.Net has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this works for Maven 3, here's what would work for Maven 2. This should work to clean the local repository:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

Otherwise, try cleaning the specific artifact from your local repository:

```
* Linux: ~/.m2
* Windows: C:\Documents and Settings\USER\.m2
```